# py2exe and msvcr100.dll. The dll is not valid

Tags: python, windows, py2exe

I'm trying to make an exe for a python program I developed, with py2exe. I managed to do it, but I can't figure out the last problem I have: include the msvcr100.dll.

I tried to follow the tutorial here: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

But they do it with an old version of Visual Studio. I installed visual studio 2010 express, and the files are not even in the same directory.

So, as my program will be used by only one person, I simply copied the dll in the same directory as the exe. But when I try to run the exe on a  fresh windows install, I get an error message:
"The application or the dll MSVCR100.dll is not a valid windows "image" (translation from french, sorry. I don't even know what that means in my own language).

Could you give me a hand please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't install Visual Studio. Install Visual C++ Redistributable [2008](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29) and [2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555).

Comment: Ok, thanks, if I install that on a windows fresh install, my program runs. But isn't there a way to include the dll in my dist directory ? I just want the final user to click on the exe to run the program. If possible, no side install.

Comment: I don't know how you installed Py2exe but you should use the installer from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/py2exe/0.6.9/) for your appropriate version.

Comment: I'm using the version 3.4, and I don't see it in the list. I install py2exe with pip. Does that matter ? The version from sourceforge does something more ?

Comment: Oh, I thought you were using Python 2.7. Anyway, look [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/0.9.2.0#downloads).

Comment: Ok, I installed py2exe that way. But now I get errors I don't get with the py2exe installed with pip. So really, what is the advantage to install py2exe from the website ?